# Different readings of voltmeter on simple circuit

Tags: qucs

Hi I am trying to learn the basics of electronics and puzzled by the following qucs simulation.

Why the readings of voltmeters are different? I would expect, by the way zero readings on both voltmeters as they are basically breaking the circuit one for another.

At least the readings should be symmetric but they are not.

[image]

Comment: What are the internal resistances of the meters?

Comment: They cannot be configured, so I assume they are ideal, e.g. infinite resistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the impedance of the virtual meters is infinite - breaking the circuit. You may get better results by putting a 10 megaohm resistor in parallel with the meter.

Edit: [this modification of your circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0Ar%20160%20112%20368%20112%200%201000%0Av%20160%20320%20368%20320%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ap%20160%20112%20160%20320%201%200%0Ap%20368%20112%20368%20320%201%200%0Aw%20368%20112%20432%20112%200%0Aw%20160%20112%2096%20112%200%0Aw%20160%20320%2096%20320%200%0Aw%20368%20320%20432%20320%200%0Ar%2096%20112%2096%20320%200%201000000000%0Ar%20432%20112%20432%20320%200%201000000000%0Ap%20160%20112%20160%2032%201%200%0Ap%20368%20112%20368%2032%201%200%0Ap%20368%20320%20368%20400%201%200%0Ap%20160%20320%20160%20400%201%200%0A) clears up what's going on.

[image: Falstad screenshot]

Falstad makes three simplifying assumptions:

(1) It defines an absolute voltage for purposes of simulation, rather than real voltages which are defined between two points.

(2) A voltmeter with nothing on the other end therefore produces a voltage as if the other end was connected to zero volts. Real voltmeters do not do this.

(3) Voltmeters have infinite impedance.

(4) In the original circuit at the top of the page, it looks like it arbitrarily decided that the positive terminal of the battery was to be used for "absolute zero voltage". That explains all the rest of the readings - the resistor and the right-hand terminals get assigned "absolute zero".

Not entirely broken, but all you're doing is showing how the simulation is a simplification of reality.

Comment: It means in real life it would be zero? By the way if I ground the (+), the readings are reverted. And more than that, if I just remove the resistor (by completely breaking the circuit)  the readings are still not zero (Pr2 1and Pr1 0)

Comment: If the readings are still not zero with the resistor removed then the simulator is very buggy and should not be used. Try Falstad instead.

Comment: Same on effect falstad. If build the similar circuit one (with default values) of voltemetes shows 5V and one zero.

Comment: Link the Falstad circuit here please?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/y8jhdevn

Comment: See edit to reply

Comment: Not sure I understand fully the answer (I am a complete noob) . But I was suspecting something similar to what you posted. I thought that simulation assumes that any (-) of source and also disconnected part of the circuit are grounded. Thanks in any way.Marking it as answer,.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, both voltmeter should be reading 0V. So you're right there. But in real life, if you did this experiment, both meters would not equal 0V. This is because wires have resistance that varies depending on the size wire and its length. A small voltage is being divided along the wires when the circuit is closed, so that's why your meter would not equal 0V.

Comment: No, both voltmeters should not be reading 0V but half the supply.

Comment: If these are theoretical with 0 Ohms of resistance, why wouldn't the two voltmeters read 0V? V = I * 0 = 0V.

Comment: Because then they would be ammeters. How do you develop a voltage across 0 ohms? Voltmeters have very high impedance; ideally infinite.

Answer (score 0):

In real life, I would expect the sum of the two meters' readings to equal 1 V, and that's what you've got there. So in a sense, it's not inconsistent with real life. If I had two identical meters, then I would expect each to read 0.5 V.

The simulation looks suspect. If the meters are identical, then they have resistance, or they do not. If they do, then they should each read 0.5 V. If they don't have resistance, then the simulation should fail, with a 'floating node' error (or something more obscure that means the same thing, like 'zero determinant matrix'). There's no reason to think the meters should be different in the simulator. It appears therefore that the first meter it meets somehow breaks the circuit, and it does something different for the other one.

Try the simulation again with a 10 Mohm resistor across each meter.